# Classification: ClassA vs. "everything else"

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition

I am trying to create a neural network for recognizing a particular object. Maybe I am approaching this task from the wrong side, but, in my mind, this task boils down to teaching the network to do a binary classification: "Object" or "Not object".

When I was playing with MNIST, it was simple: I had 10 outputs (one per digit) and I trained the network to maximize the corresponding output for a corresponding input digit.

But when the network should recognize only one object, how do I teach it? Intuitively, it should have only one output, which would give something like `1.0` for "Yes, this is the object" and `0.0` for "No, this is something else". I have a training set with a lot of pictures of that object. But...what would be the counter-samples during training? How do I create a set of "not objects"? I mean...it is literally *anything, but the object*.

Comment: I don't know how this is done with neural networks, but in general ML this kind of problem is called [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. And there are actually NN-based approaches for this. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy to help :) (this is too short for an answer and I'm lazy to add details)

Answer (score 0):

**There are two approaches here:**

1. Classification- This is considered binary classification. Take a set of pictures with the object, label them 1. Then take a set of pictures without the object, label them 0. Then train a CNN to distinguish. Google "Resnet50" to get started.
2. Object Detection - Given a set of images, instead of the label just being 1 or 0, the labels instead are bounding boxes of each instance of the object in each image. Then train a CNN + head to distinguish. Google "SSD Object Detection" to get started.

**Advantages of Classification:**

1. Much simpler, just a normal CNN
2. Less time to train

**Advantages of Object Detection:**

1. Shows location of object, not just whether it exists.
2. Can classify more than 1 object for a particular image

Comment: > "Then take a set of pictures without the object"

But this is the actual problem here: how do I get/produce a good enough set of training data for "non-objects"? It can be anything, i.e. it's an indefinite set.

Comment: There is a specific pattern that most objects have. Say you want to detect a circle. A circle does not have sharp edges, so good non-object training data would be pictures of a bunch of rectangles, squares, triangles.